# Mocking fetch with ofetch lib (nuxt3)

Tags: vue.js, mocking, nuxt.js, fetch-api, nuxtjs3

I have a nuxt3 app that uses the `ofetch`  package for fetching:

```
import { $fetch } from 'ofetch';
...
await $fetch(param, stuff);
```

I can't find any specific package for mocking ofetch requests and the docs doesnt say anything about it. What i found is the  `vitest-fetch-mock` package, which is working perfectly like this:

```
const fetchMocker = createFetchMock(vi);
fetchMocker.enableMocks();
fetchMocker.mockResponse(JSON.stringify({ response: 'ok' }));
```

but only for the native  `fetch()`, not for the  `ofetch` version.

Is there any way to mock ofetch requests like this with the native?